# Programmatically create a ram fs under OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a program that will create files on disk and another one that reads these files. I want to speed this up a bit and dont go nuts on the harddrive. Is it possible to create a temporary ramfs filesystem programmatically in OSX to store the files to? I have no influence on the program that creates the files to alter the output or use shared memory, etc. It has to be the files on Harddrive (unfortunately).

Comment: Does "programmatically" mean you are writing a sandboxed macOS application, or does it mean a script? And do you have root privileges?

Comment: I am writing an application, but not sandboxed.

Comment: Have you considered creating a [ramdisk](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-create-a-4gbs-ram-disk-in-mac-os-x/) You should be able to do this without sudo privileges. You can access the resulting RAM disk via the path `/Volumes/RAM\ Disk`